# How to calculate the average distance ratio? That the distance are between a point inside two internally tangent circles and one on each circle

Tags: integration, plane-geometry

Consider one point $E$ and two circle $c_1$ with center $C$ and radius $r_1$ , and circle $c_2$ with center $A$ and radius $r_2$, $E$ is inside two circles, and two circles are internally tangent in $D$. We have $|DE|=a$ and $ r_2>r_1>a>0$, point $A,C,E$ are on the same line, $F$ are any point on circle $c_1$, draw a line through $E,F$ and cross $c_2$ in $G$, then we define a ratio R of distance:
$$R=\frac{|EF|}{|EG|}$$
where$|*|$ means the distance between two points.

How to calculate the average of $R$ when point $F$ goes around the whole circle $c_1$?
Or in other words, how to calculate the integration below:

$$E(R)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2 \pi } \frac{\sqrt{(r_1-a+r_1 \cos (\theta ))^2+(r_1 \sin (\theta ))^2}}{\sqrt{(r_2-a+r_2 \cos (\theta ))^2+(r_2 \sin (\theta ))^2}} \, d\theta$$
[image: Fig. 1 A brief relative of them]

Comment: The notations in the drawing do not match the ones in the text: in the figure, the circles are $c$ and $d$, not $A$ and $C$. Please make all the notations agree, otherwise the question is confusing. Furthermore, it is not clear a priori that $E(R)$ has an explicit formula.

Comment: Well, I edit the drawing and make the notations agree, and change some descriptions. Is that clear or any suggestions?

Comment: Oh, now I got it: $\odot$ was the symbol for the center point. Sorry, that's not a universally used notation, I wasn't aware of it.